# Procedure with if/else

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to create a procedure that takes in a number greater than 0 and less than 1 to be used as a discount amount. I also need to create an exception if the user puts in a number outside my parameters.

I created the following procedure but it does not compile and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Any ideas?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
 PROCEDURE prod_disc
  (p_disc IN DECIMAL)
IS
 DECLARE
  my_excep EXCEPTION;
 BEGIN
 UPDATE
  xx_product
   SET p_discount = (p_discount + p_disc)
   WHERE p_qoh >= (p_min * 2);
 IF p_disc > 0 OR p_disc < 1 THEN
  RAISE my_excep;
 END IF;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN my_excep THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: Value must be greater than 0 and less than 1');
END;
```

/
SHOW ERRORS;
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
/

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It doesn't compile. I'm using Oracle apex and get 'success with compilation error'

Comment: I will edit your question then run it to show errors.

Comment: Please add / then enter  show errors;  then /. Please run it then it will display the errors.

Comment: added the error. unfortunately thats all APEX gives me

Comment: You can query `user_errors`, or else use a proper development tool for PL/SQL as you surely would for any other programming language.

Comment: Hi Giles  - your logic to check for legal values should come first in your code - there's no point in doing the UPDATE if the value is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DECLARE` is a surplus - remove it.

Also, instead of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`, use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` because noone will ever see the result of the former (unless (s)he runs in in a tool that supports such an output. The latter will be seen *everywhere*.

Fixed, your code might look like this (I'm not checking its logic):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prod_disc (p_disc IN DECIMAL)
IS
   my_excep   EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   UPDATE xx_product
      SET p_discount = (p_discount + p_disc)
    WHERE p_qoh >= (p_min * 2);

   IF    p_disc > 0
      OR p_disc < 1
   THEN
      RAISE my_excep;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN my_excep
   THEN
      raise_application_error (
         -20000,
         'Error: Value must be greater than 0 and less than 1');
END;
/
```

Comment: It appears it is raising the my exception with any value i try. It compiled properly but i tried executing it 
BEGIN
prod_disc(0.2);
END;

for example

Comment: 0.2 is between 0 and 1, so exception is raised. You should switch the condition upside down and raise it if parameter is less than 0 and higher than 1.

Comment: oh duh...rookie mistake! Let me try that and see if that fixes it.

Comment: All fixed! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove ; in EXCEPTION clause

```
OLD: 
 EXCEPTION;
 WHEN my_excep THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: Value must be greater than 0 and less than 1');

NEW: 
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN my_excep THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: Value must be greater than 0 and less than 1');
```

Comment: fixed the exception clause.

Answer (score 0):

remove '**DECLARE**' keyword
You can declare variables after the '**IS**' keyword since its built as the declaration part of the procedure/function without putting the keyword '**DECLARE**'